# Python Bluetooth MODBUS RTU

Tags: python, bluetooth, modbus

I am attempting to create a python application that is able to communicate over Bluetooth with my DPS3005 power supply module. I found [this](https://github.com/Haschtl/PyDPS) GitHub repository which implements what I wish to do however it utilises the now deprecated `rfcomm connect rfcomm0 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` command.

I believe I should be able to achieve the same functionality using Bluetooth sockets in python and have written the following code:

```
# ------------------------------ Imports modules ----------------------------- #
import bluetooth
import time
import struct

# ----------------------------- Program Constants ---------------------------- #
DEVICE_ADDRESS = "98:DA:20:01:13:09"
DEVICE_PORT = 1

# ------------------------ Connect to bluetooth device ----------------------- #
sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
sock.connect((DEVICE_ADDRESS,DEVICE_PORT))
print("Connected to device!")

time.sleep(0.005)

# ------------------------ Attempt to send data packet ----------------------- #
# Set voltage to 21v
req = struct.pack('10B',
                    0x01, #Start Bit
                    0x01, #Slave Address
                    0x06, #Function Code (0x06 = Write Single Register)
                    0x00, 0x00, #Register Address (0x0000 = Voltage Set Register)
                    0x08, 0x34, #Register Value (0x0834 = 21.00v)
                    0xFB, 0xB2, #CRC Checksum values
                    0x01 #End Bit
                    )

print("TX: (%s)" % req)

sock.send(req)
print("Data Sent!")

# ----------------------------- Close connection ----------------------------- #
sock.close()
```

I used [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vocTn9vJhjGpIlWfe6TXeIIdju2sELHo/view?usp=sharing) document provided by the manufacturer to try and understand how I need to structure my message to the device however it does not appear to understand my request.

I am quite new to working with communications in this low-level way and I would like to ask if such a transmission is in accordance with the MODBUS RTU specification pictured below and specifically what the start and stop bits should be.

Clippings from afore mentioned specification document:
[image]
and
[image: Voltage Set Example]

Many thanks for any suggestions and help!

Comment: You cannot change the bytes in the message without also updating the CRC - try `01 06 00 00 08 34 8F DD` (test with [this parser](https://rapidscada.net/modbus/ModbusParser.aspx)); also don't send the "start" or "end" bit. I'd also suggest checking for a response from the device.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your comment; will check this tomorrow - that is a good point about the CRC. I did try to receive data previously during test but that didn't seem to do anything - does it matter what value if put inside `sock.recv()`? I believe this is the number of bytes of something.

Comment: Unfortunately the responses are a variable size (depending upon the request and any error) so it's not as simple as that... Handling the response is not essential but does enable your code to detect if something is going wrong (and get data from the device). If you decide to go that route then consider using a library (e.g. pymodbus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you very much 'Brits' for you comment. I managed to get my software working using this subroutine I wrote to calculate a CRC value according to the provided specification.

```
# ----------------------- Calculate the CRC Check Value ---------------------- #
def calcCRC(data):
    register = 0xFFFF

    for byte in data:
        register ^= byte
        for i in range(8):
            lsb = register & 1
            register = register >> 1
            if lsb:
                register ^= 0xA001
        
    return register & 0xff, register >> 8 #Return the higher and lower bytes
```